# How do we initialize variables in ASP.NET Core dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am migrating my application to .Net Core, so previously I had used Simple Injector, but am trying to move to .Net Core inbuilt DI.

I have an interface like this,

```
public interface ICheckPeriod
{
   int Max { get; set; }
   int Seed { get; set; }
}
```

So using SI, I had done like this,

```
RegisterInitializer<ICheckPeriod>(checkPeriod =>
{
    checkPeriod.Seed = 2;
    checkPeriod.Max = 7;
});
```

What is the equivalent for it in ASP.NET Core's DI ?

Comment: Before migrating to a different DI Container, you should first verify whether that container has all the functionality you require. The Core DI Container is very limitef in functionality.

Comment: Sounds to me like you'd rather want to use the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Whatever you do, [do not use `IOptions<T>` in your application components](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html#working-with-ioptions-t). And no, it is not a _pattern_.

Comment: Initializing dependencies this way, however, is typically not the best solution, since it leads to Temporal Coupling. Prefer injecting configuration objects into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are using this, but you could just create an implementation with the default values and inject it.

```
public interface ICheckPeriod
{
    int Max { get; set; }
    int Seed { get; set; }
}

public class CheckPeriod : ICheckPeriod
{
    public int Max { get; set; } = 2;
    public int Seed { get; set; } = 7;
}

services.AddTransient<ICheckPeriod, CheckPeriod>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent solution in core DI would be to register the class as a singleton

```
public interface ICheckPeriod
{
    int Max { get; set; }
    int Seed { get; set; }
}

public class CheckPeriod : ICheckPeriod
{
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Seed { get; set; }
}

var checkPeriod = new CheckPeriod { Max = 2, Seed = 7 };
services.AddSingleton<ICheckPeriod>(checkPeriod);
```